# частичная группировака в запросе mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго всем времени суток, 2й раз за сегодня

```
$zapros = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `table` GROUP BY `data`,$db);
```

Есть дата, вида 0000-00-00 00:00:00. Безумно хочется сделать ей GROUP BY, причем по месяцам (т.е. первые 7 символов). Как это сделать ест-но не пойму. Подскажите, как решить такую задачу?

Comment: GROUP BY MONTH(data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GROUP BY YEAR(field_date), MONTH(field_date)
```

или

```
GROUP BY LAST_DAY(field_date)
```

Comment: идеально подошла команда

    GROUP BY LAST_DAY(field_date)

т.к. в моем случае данные даты больше чем с промежутком 1 год. в остальных случаях подходят все упомянутые в теме ответы. спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

а если `GROUP BY MONTH(`data`)`